# Nest Next and Previous in a href with class that has a background image

Tags: posts, single

How do I nest Next and Previous link in a href attribute that has a class and background image in a single post page?

I want to make it something like the below which is not working.

```
<a class="next" href="<?php echo $prev; ?>">Previous</a>
<a class="prev" href="<?php echo $next; ?>">Next</a>
```

Here is the link to a sample site: http://ifunnypic.com/dad-i-m-gay_3317.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

In single.php you should be using: `<?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous'); ?>` and `<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next'); ?>`. 
Then you add this to your functions.php:

```
function filter_next_post_link($link) {
    $link = str_replace("rel=", 'class="next" rel=', $link);
    return $link;
}
add_filter('next_post_link', 'filter_next_post_link');

function filter_previous_post_link($link) {
    $link = str_replace("rel=", 'class="prev" rel=', $link);
    return $link;
}
add_filter('previous_post_link', 'filter_previous_post_link');
```

Although this is not the answer to this question, but to paginate in categories you should be looking into `next_posts_link_attributes` and `previous_posts_link_attributes` hooks. Just add this to your functions.php:

```
function next_posts_link_css($content) { 
    return 'class="next"';
}
function previous_posts_link_css($content) { 
    return 'class="prev"';
}

add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'next_posts_link_css' );
add_filter('previous_posts_link_attributes', 'previous_posts_link_css' );
```

Just to clarify. You'll be using the usual pagination in your template files:

```
<?php previous_posts_link('Previous') ?>
<?php next_posts_link('Next') ?>
```

Comment: Hi, @daniel-sachs I tried it, but nothing showed up in the single post page. To make it more clear here is the sample link: http://ifunnypic.com/dad-i-m-gay_3317.html

Comment: hmmm, sorry,I missed the "single post" part. In single.php you should be using: `<?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous'); ?>` and `<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next'); ?>` . Then you add this to your functions.php: `function filter_next_post_link($link) {
    $link = str_replace("rel=", 'class="next" rel=', $link);
    return $link;
}
add_filter('next_post_link', 'filter_next_post_link');

function filter_previous_post_link($link) {
    $link = str_replace("rel=", 'class="prev" rel=', $link);
    return $link;
}
add_filter('previous_post_link', 'filter_previous_post_link');`